# NGRX Select returning Store not a value

Tags: ngrx, ngrx-store, rxjs-observables, ngrx-reducers

[catalogueSelection in Store Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HqkYB.png)

I have the data I require in state (catalogueSelection: searchTextResult & categoryCheckboxResult)  and need to pass the string 'SearchTextResult' into one component and the Array 'categoryCheckboxResult' into another.

When I try to retrieve the required values I am retrieving the whole store. I have looked at numerous websites and entries here but getting very confused now.

#### Model:

```
export class SearchTextResult {
  searchTextResult: string;
}

export class CategoryCheckboxResult {
  categoryCheckboxResult:Array<CategoryCheckboxResult>;
}
```

#### Actions:

```
import { Action } from '@ngrx/store';
import { SearchTextResult, CategoryCheckboxResult } from 'app/@core/services/products/products.model';

export enum UserCatalogueSelectionTypes {
    AddSearchTextResult = '[SearchTextResult] AddResult',
    AddCategoryCheckboxResult = '[CategoryCheckboxResult] AddResult',
    GetSearchTextResult = '[SearchTextResult] GetResult',
}

export class AddSearchTextResult implements Action {
    readonly type = UserCatalogueSelectionTypes.AddSearchTextResult;
    constructor(public payload: SearchTextResult){
    }
}

export class AddCategoryCheckboxResult implements Action {
    readonly type = UserCatalogueSelectionTypes.AddCategoryCheckboxResult;
    constructor(public payload: CategoryCheckboxResult){
    }
}

export class GetSearchTextResult implements Action {
    readonly type = UserCatalogueSelectionTypes.GetSearchTextResult;
}

export type UserCatalogueSelectionUnion =
| AddSearchTextResult
| AddCategoryCheckboxResult
| GetSearchTextResult
```

#### Reducers:

```
import { SearchTextResult, CategoryCheckboxResult} from "app/@core/services/products/products.model";
import { UserCatalogueSelectionTypes,  UserCatalogueSelectionUnion} from "../actions/products.actions";


export interface UserCatalogueSelectionState {
 searchTextResult: SearchTextResult | null;
 categoryCheckboxResult: CategoryCheckboxResult | null;
}

export const initialState: UserCatalogueSelectionState = {
    searchTextResult: null,
    categoryCheckboxResult: null,
}

 
export function reducer(state:UserCatalogueSelectionState = initialState, action: UserCatalogueSelectionUnion ): UserCatalogueSelectionState{
    switch (action.type) {
        case UserCatalogueSelectionTypes.AddSearchTextResult: 
            return {
                ...state, 
                searchTextResult: action.payload,
            };
        
        case UserCatalogueSelectionTypes.AddCategoryCheckboxResult: 
            return {
                ...state, 
                categoryCheckboxResult: action.payload,
            };

        case UserCatalogueSelectionTypes.GetSearchTextResult: {
            return state;
        }
            
        default: {
            return state;
        }

    }
}
```

#### Selectors:

```
import { createSelector,createFeatureSelector } from "@ngrx/store";
import {UserCatalogueSelectionState} from '../../store/reducer/products.reducer';

export const fetchSearchTextResults = createFeatureSelector<UserCatalogueSelectionState>("searchTextResult");

export const fetchSearchTextResult = createSelector (
    fetchSearchTextResults,
    (state:UserCatalogueSelectionState) => state.searchTextResult.searchTextResult
);

export const fetchCatalogueCheckBoxResults = createFeatureSelector<UserCatalogueSelectionState>("catalogueCheckboxResult");

export const fetchCatalogueCheckBoxResult = createSelector (
    fetchCatalogueCheckBoxResults,
    (state: UserCatalogueSelectionState) => state.categoryCheckboxResult.categoryCheckboxResult
);
```

## My Component 1

#### Observable:

```
public searchTextResult: Observable<String>;
```

#### Contructor: (part of)

```
private store: Store<fromCatalogueSelection.UserCatalogueSelectionState>
```

#### Code Snippet: (asking for the data)

```
this.searchTextResult = this.store.select('SearchTextResult');
console.log('TESTING SEARCH TEXT: ', this.searchTextResult);
```

#### Console:

> TESTING SEARCH TEXT:  Store {_isScalar: false, actionsObserver: ActionsSubject, reducerManager: >ReducerManager, source: Store, operator: DistinctUntilChangedOperator}

## My Component 2

#### Observable

```
searchTextResult$: Observable<CatalogueSelectionActions.GetSearchTextResult>;
```

#### Code Snippet: (asking for the data)

```
this.searchTextResult$ = this.store.select('GetSearchTextResult');
console.log('TESTING SEARCH TEXT: ', this.searchTextResult$);
```

#### Console:

> TESTING SEARCH TEXT:  Store {_isScalar: false, actionsObserver: ActionsSubject, reducerManager: > ReducerManager, source: Store, operator: DistinctUntilChangedOperator}

I've given up on the Selectors for the moment. Any help much appreciated as I'm going a round in circles.

Answer (score 2):

You are almost there, the value from the console log is the `observable` object, everytime you select something from the store, you will get the value wrapped within an `observable`. You just need to `subscribe` to it:

```js
this.searchTextResult$ = this.store.select('GetSearchTextResult');
this.searchTextResult$.subscribe((yourData) => console.log(yourData));
```

Also, since you are working with `selectors`, use them, you don't have to write the state/selector name:

**selector**

```js
...
export const fetchCatalogueCheckBoxResult = createSelector (
    fetchCatalogueCheckBoxResults,
    (state: UserCatalogueSelectionState) => 
      state.categoryCheckboxResult.categoryCheckboxResult
);
```

**component**

```js
import * as YourSelectors from './store/something/selectors/yourthing.selectors'

...
...
this.searchTextResult$ = this.store
    .select(YourSelectors.fetchCatalogueCheckBoxResult)
    .subscribe(console.log);
```

Additionally, try to `subscribe` using the `async` pipe delegating that to your template html so you don't have to deal with the subscription in the code, for example:

**component**

```js
...
export class Component {
  searchTextResult$!: Observable<any> // your data type here
...
...
this.searchTextResult$ = this.store
    .select(YourSelectors.fetchCatalogueCheckBoxResult)
}
```

**html**

```html
<ng-container *ngIf="(searchTextResult$ | async) as result">
  <p>Your result value: {{ result }}</p>
</ng-container>
```

Comment: Sorry no feedback from me, I've been moved to another issue, will look at your suggestions next week.